# For loops indexing in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use for loops to calculate the following formula: 
[image]

However, since the number of elements for 't' and 'tau' are different, I'm not sure how to properly index the code.

This is what I have done so far:

```
t = [0:0.1:15];
tau = [0:2:10];
dtau = tau(2)-tau(1);

BB = 4*tau;
u = 2*t;
B = zeros(1,length(t));

for ii = 1:length(t)
    for jj = 1:length(tau)
        B(ii) = B(ii) + BB(jj)*u(ii-jj+1)*dtau;
    end
end
```

To elaborate a bit more - the upper integration limit is the 't' in this case, so for every B(t) I would like to integrate from tau(0) to tau=t. Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: So... can't you just go `conv(BB,u)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing convolution so just use Matlab's built-in functions if you can i.e. `conv`. But here is a loopy version for your understanding:

using your data

```
t = [0:0.1:15];
tau = [0:2:10];
dtau = tau(2)-tau(1);

BB = 4*tau;
u = 2*t;
B = zeros(1,length(t));
```

We flip `u` and then slide it over `BB'. It's easiest to just pad BB with zeros so you don't have to deal with edges:

```
U = fliplr(u);
BB = [zeros(1,length(u)-1), BB, zeros(1,length(u)-1)];

for ii = 1:length(t)   %//This should actually go to 21, I don't feel like working out why right now
    B(ii) = sum(U.*BB(ii:(ii+length(u)-1)));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

If you want to do it like that, you only have to define `tau` inside the `for ii = 1:length(t)` loop, that's all.

So it would look something like this:

```
t = [0:0.1:15];

u = 2*t;
B = zeros(1,length(t));

for ii = 1:length(t)

    tau = [0:0.2*ii:ii]
    dtau = tau(2)-tau(1);
    BB = 4*tau;    

    for jj = 1:length(tau)
        B(ii) = B(ii) + BB(jj)*u(ii-jj+1)*dtau;
    end
end
```

That being said, I think Dan's comment is on spot: unless you want to play with the parameters by yourself, you are performing a simple convolution there.

Comment: Also your ii loop is set to 1, you might want to set it to 0.1, or whatever the t step is.

Comment: `ii` is running through the indices of `t`, so it would work as expected if he plots `B` over `t`. It won't work as `B(some_t)` though.

Comment: My bad, you are right there ;) but then he has to define `tau` inside the loop accordingly.